# Is a lift of a general map necessarily continuous?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm currently studying on the topics covering space, using Gamelin's topology. The author defines a lift as follows:

> Let $p: E \to X$ be a covering map, let $Y$ be a topological space, and $f : Y \to X$ be a map. If a map $g :Y \to E$ satisfies $ p\circ g = f$, then $g$ is called a $\textbf{lift}$ of $f$.

What confuses me is that when the text is trying to prove the lift uniqueness property:

> Let $p,E,X,Y$ be as above. We further require that $Y$ to be connected. Suppose $g,h$ are two lifts of $f$, and $g(y) =h(y)$ for some $y \in Y$, then $g= h$.

The proof uses the fact that $g$ and $h$ are continuous to conclude. However, since the text doesn't assume that $f,g,$ and $g$ to be continuous, I'm wondering whether the continuity of $g,h$ actually are implied by the definitions implicitly, hence making it unnecessary to include the continuity of $g,h$ explicitly.

I also looked up Hatcher's Algebraic topology, and neither does Hatcher require that the lifts should be continuous, and he also uses the continuity of lifts in his proof.

I can't figure out the continuity of the lifts, and I'd like to ask how can I deduce that $g,h$ are actually continuous maps from the definition? Thanks.

Comment: Generally, lifts are consider in a specific category, here you are in Top, so yes $p$ is required to be a morphism of this category (it needs to be consistent). Lifts here are thus continuous.

Comment: Hatcher's book is definitely assuming continuity unless otherwise specified (it was stated at the beginning of chapter 0).  I haven't checked Gamelin but I assume it is the same.

Comment: In topology, "map" often means "continuous function". Check the book's definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detail my comment, lifts are omnipresent in homotopy theory or differential geometry. They are inherent to the framework you are working in. If you are working in differential geometry, they need to be smooth, if you are working in topological homotopy theory, they need to be continuous.

Lifts are formally defined in a category $C$ as such:
If you have a morphism (usually a projection) $p: E \to B$ and another morphism $f:A \to B$, a lift is a morphism (thus in $C$) $g$ that verifies $p\circ g = f$.

Here in Top, this means that $g$ is **continuous**.

You often want to prove that $p:E \to B$ has the *lifting property* with respect to a certain class of morphisms $W$ that have $B$ for target. This means that for any $f:A \to B \in W$, there exists a lift $g$.

- A first example would be for fibre bundles, you want to be able to "get back" to your simpler space $E$ for some well chosen morphisms.
- You can have variants, e.g. in homotopy theory, you have $p:E \to B$ has the *homotopy lifting property* with respect to a topological space $A$, if for any commutative diagram given by $i_0: X \to X \times [0,1]$, $H_0: X \to E$, $h: X \times [0,1] \to E$ , where $i_0(x) = (x,0)$, (i.e. $h_0 = h \circ i_0 = p \circ H_0$), there exists a filling of the diagram $H: X\times I \to E$ (i.e. $H_0 = H \circ i_0$ and $p\circ H = h$).
  The motivation here is that you can extend any homotopy from your "projected" space $B$ to your easier to deal with but much bigger space $E$.